# React 409 Error code when trying to POST new user

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a component that creates a new user. The backend is a restful asp.net core that has been tested and works. When I try to add a new user I get the error

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 409`

I've seen previous answers that the URL/location provided inside the POST method is not correct, but I've double, triple checked. Is this something I've overlooked?

AddUser.js

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Input, InputLabel, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { addUser } from "../Services/api";

const initialValues = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  username: '',
}

const AddUser = () => {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(initialValues);
  const { firstName, lastName, username } = user;

  const onValueChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  const addUserDetails = async () => {
    await addUser(user);
  }

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>First Name</InputLabel>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} name='firstName' value={firstName} />
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>Last Name</InputLabel>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} name='lastName' value={lastName} />
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>Username</InputLabel>
        <Input onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)} name='username' value={username} />
      </FormControl>
      <Button varient="contained" onClick={() => addUserDetails()}>Add New User</Button>
    </FormGroup>
  )
}

export default AddUser;
```

api.js

```
const url = "https://localhost:44326/api/Users";

export const getUsers = () => {
  return axios.get(url);
}

export const addUser = async(user) => {
  return axios.post(url, user);
}
```

Comment: 409 typically means conflict, ie it may be that a user with this data (especially the username) already exists on the server, so it cannot be created. You will have to check your server WHY exacty it returns 409 ...

Comment: Ahh just tested this by deleting id 0 and it works! BUT it doesn't auto-increment itself, is that a server error or front end?

Comment: Well, you are probably not supposed to create userids on the client, but it's the server's responsibility to create unique ids. So it's for sure a server error. And if you are creating user ids on the client, you should immeditely rethink your design, because that's going to blow up ... Seems your serverside is not so well tested, after all ...